# Issue with uploading using CarrierWave_Direct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm pretty new to ruby and rails and I'm having some problems uploading using carrierwave_direct. I followed Ryan Bates' Railscast 383 on uploading using carrierwave_direct. However, the solution he provides doesn't seem to be working for me. I have a User model that I created using Devise and I have an uploader that handles my uploading. I am trying to use the uploader to upload video files which I plan to later transcode using the Elastic Transoder with the AWS API. The files are uploading fine to s3, but it appears that they are not getting associated with a record in my database.The files upload as soon as I submit them, but I need a way to create them along with a title, a description, and potentially other parameters later. My if-else statement always redirects to my else statement as well. I think my problem is in my controller; my routes and views seem to be working fine, I'm just stuck on this one issue.

To clarify further: I need users to be able to upload a video and then have the user input a title, description, etc. and then be redirected to another page. I then need to be able to show that file later when called upon.

Here is my UploadsController:

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :destroy]
before_action :current_user, only: :destroy

  def index
    @uploader = Upload.new.video
    @uploader.success_action_redirect = new_uploads_url
  end

  def show
    @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @upload = Upload.new(key: params[:key])
  end

  def create
    @upload = Upload.new(upload_params)
      if @upload.save
      redirect_to home_index_path
      return
    else
      redirect_to uploads_index_path
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
    @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
    @upload.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Upload deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end


  def upload_params
    params.require(:upload).permit(:video, :title, :description)
  end
end
```

Here is my Upload Model:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true, length: {maximum: 100}
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :video, presence: true
  mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader

  after_save :enqueue_video

  def enqueue_video
    VideoWorker.perform_async(id, key) if key.present?
  end

 class VideoWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform(id, key)
     upload = Upload.find(id)
     upload.key = key
     video.remote_video_url = upload.video.direct_fog_url(with_path: true)
     upload.save!
    end
 end
end
```

And my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/home/index'

  root 'home#index'

  devise_for :users

  get 'users/:id' => 'users#show'

  resources :uploads

  get '/index' => 'uploads#index'

end
```

**EDIT** Here is my UsersController and User Show Page as well:

Controller:
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

```
  def show 
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Show:

```
<h1><%= @user.username %></h1>

<h3>Title:</h3>
<%= @upload.title %>
```

Comment: My suspicion is that there are validation errors on `@upload`. Are you showing `@upload.errors` somewhere? If not, what is its value?

Comment: So, you were right about the validations. I didn't have any validation tests so I just removed the validations, tried another file upload and then the redirect worked. However, when I attempted to access the @upload, it did not show up on the user show page. Is the information of the record not being put into my database? Or could it be something else?

Comment: It's difficult to say; if `@upload.save` returned `true` then it's probably saved to the database. Make sure it actually *is* by using something like `Upload.last` from `rails console`. It's possible that the record is in the database, but that the `user_id` is missing since you removed all validations. Removing validations is not a fix, looking what the error is and fixing *that* is the fix :-) You could also have an error in the controller rendering the show or view code.

Comment: I edited the original question and put the UsersController and Users Show page up as well. I just wanted to test whether or not the validations were what was stopping my redirect. I added the user_id validation back and it failed the redirect. I'm just so lost on this issue.

Comment: After running the command you recommended in the console it returned my last uploaded file! So, is this likely a view/controller problem with my User Show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing:

```
def create
    @upload = Upload.new(upload_params)
    # [..]
end

def upload_params
    params.require(:upload).permit(:video, :title, :description)
end
```

And that your `Upload` is linked to a `User` with:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    # [..]
end
```

So how does Rails know which `Upload` belongs to which `User`? You never told `Upload` anything 'bout no `User`!

If you always want to use the currently logged in user, you could probably do something like:

```
def create
    @upload = Upload.new(upload_params)
    @upload.user = current_user
    # [...]
end
```

This assumes, of course, that `current_user` is the correct method to get the currently logged in user (it usually is).

If you want to be able to connect it to any other user, you need to add a `user_id` field in the and add it to `upload_params`.

Comment: That was it! I now am having the User seamlessly associated with the Upload! This was my first experience actually asking on Stack Overflow and you've been awesome! I should be able to figure it out from here. Haha hopefully.